# How to implement Facebook namespace into my MVC 3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got an MVC 3 application I'm trying to use Facebook authentication on, but for whatever reason the namespace isn't being recognized in my app.

In my _Layout.cshtml file (master page for MVC 3), I put:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Then in my home Index:

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <p>
        <fb:login-button v="2" size="medium" onlogin="window.location.reload(true);">My Facebook Account</fb:login-button>
    </p>
```

When the page renders, it shows the My Facebook Account text, but no button!

Visual Studio is also complaining that "fb is an unrecognized namespace"...

Are the namespaces passed down to the views?  Why is "fb" not being recognized, even if it's in the _Layout.cshtml?